# retrieving date of uploaded files in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is there a way that I can retrieve the date in which a file was uploaded in a sharepoint list using sharepoint web services? I need to use web services because my app is going to be installed in a client computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sharepoint `Lists.asmx` Webservice (`http://<Site>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`) to check the created or modified date of uploaded file in SharePoint.

This webservice will return the xml document similar like this:

```
<listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
   xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
   xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <rs:data ItemCount="4">
      <z:row ows_Number_Field="6555.00000000000" 
         ows_Created="2003-06-18T03:41:09Z" 
         ows_Modified="2009-07-02 14:16:18
         ows_ID="3" ows_owshiddenversion="3" />
      <z:row ows_Number_Field="78905456.0000000" 
         ows_Created="2003-06-18T17:15:58Z" 
         ows_Modified="2009-07-02 14:16:18"
         ows_ID="4" ows_owshiddenversion="2" />
         ...
   </rs:data>
</listitems>
```

The tedious part in working with sharepoint webservice is writing(with CAML) parameter to pass into the webservice and retrieving values from returned xml document. See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28office.12%29.aspx) for the sample.

I also found some blog which using with LINQ to XML and it seems more easier to use. Please check below link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/01/06/getting-started-with-sharepoint-wss-web-services-using-linq-to-xml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a great tool too FYI: http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx